# Parsing Quantum Assembly Language text files in Julia

Tags: regex, file, parsing, text, julia

Quantum Asembly Language (QASM) - a human readable text that declares classical bits and qubits along with operations (gates) that should be applited to those bits.

Here is a simple example of a typical QASM program that can be executed on a quantum computer:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q[2]; # define two quantum registers
h q[1]; # apply Hadamard gate on qubit 1
cx q[0], q[1]; # apply Controlled Not on qubit 0 and 1
u(pi/2, pi/4, pi/2) q[0]; # apply the parametrized gate `u` with angles pi/2, pi/4, pi/2
```

Note that the order of operations in the QASM file matters.

I would like to know the best way to parse such a file in Julia. Specifically, given a QASM file, I woud like to have a datastructure that contains the following information:

```
circuit_gates[1] = ["h", [1], None] # gate name, qubit, no params
circuit_gates[2] = ["cx", [0,1], None] # gate name, qubits, no params
circuit_gates[3] = ["u", [0], [angle_1, angle_2, angle_3]] # gate name, qubit, gate params
```

I come from Python background, and work with QASM is straighforward due to high-level libraries like Qiskit. I want to try Julia for its speed, but my knowledge of Julia is very superficial.

What would be the best approach to parse QASM file into the indicated strucutre above?

I'm thinking about using [Regex](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/) but it looks somewhat cumbersome. Given that QASM files are fairly structured maybe there are ways to split file into fields that could be converted into some table?

Comment: You might try [OpenQasm.jl](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/ann-openqasm-jl-the-openqasm-parser-for-julia/60129) and the Yao.jl ecosystem